# Resetting value of dependent field on hide in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with a radio button asking a question with a Yes/No response. If the user selects Yes, then a drop down appears which is a required field. If the user selects No, then this drop down does not appear.

In the case that the user answers Yes and then chooses a value from the drop-down, then goes back later and changes the answer to No, I want the selected value in the drop-down to be removed (set to '' for example).

How do I do this in AngularJS?

At the moment, what is happening is that the radio box value is set to No, but I am still retaining the value originally selected in the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways:

1. Watch for the radio button value and set the drop down value to '' when the radio button value is 'No'.
2. On ng-click of 'No' radio button set the drop down value to ''.

If I am doing it I will choose No. 2 to reduce the watch because watch is a heavy hammer approach.